# Bit update operation using bit wise coding style

Tags: c++, arduino, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I want to update a bit of 5-bit long data irrespective of what is the status of other bits i.e. every bit should independently behave with respect to other bits in 5-bits long data. below is my code. Any suggestion will be really helpful for me.

```
case 35:
    AtemSwitcher.setTransitionNextTransition(0,(a=00001<<1));   
    break;
case 36:
    AtemSwitcher.setTransitionNextTransition(0,(b=00001<<2));
    break;
case 37:
    AtemSwitcher.setTransitionNextTransition(0,(c=00001<<3));
    break;
case 38:
    AtemSwitcher.setTransitionNextTransition(0,(d=00001<<4));
    break;
```

Comment: You need a bitwise OR operation `|` to set or a bitwise AND (`&`) to unset.... or.. what was the question?

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/bits-and-bytes/bitwrite/

Comment: Aside: be wary of your "5 bit data". Do you know the effect of using leading zeros in your numbers? `00001` is never anything but `1`. However `00100` is not a binary number with decimal value `4`. It is not the decimal number value `100`. It is an octal number with decimal value `64`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to only operate on specific bits you will need to use masking operations with OR, AND and XOR:

For setting one bit you will need to use bitwise OR:

```
c = c | (1 << 4);
c |= 1 << 4; //set bit number 4
c |= (1 << 4) | (1 << 3); //set bit 4 and 3
```

For setting a bit to 0, you will need to use bitwise AND:

```
c &= ~(1 << 4); //delete bit 4
```

The Reason, why you also need the ~ operator is, because an & operation will be 0 if any of the inputs is 0, so you want to set the bits you want to clear to 0, so that they will be 0 in the result.

You can also toggle a bit with the use of a bitwise XOR:

```
c ^= (1 << 4); //toggle bit 4
```